# Removing version control executable link in global options under R Studio?

Tags: version-control, rstudio

In R studio, under Tools > Global Options > Git/SVN > SVN Executable, I originally linked R studio to a version control software we no longer use. After it was uninstalled, R studio would give me errors trying to open a removed .exe file so I set it to something simple in the interim calc.exe.

Unfortunately, now when I open R Studio, it opens up the calculator and needs me to specifically close it before it will continue to open.

I'd like to ask how I can set the .exe to blank or remove the link or need for an .exe completely so R studio will open quickly without me needing to close anything it opens. Note that I cannot re-install R studio because our IT department insists on not supporting our use of R Studio despite allowing it's being installed; in other words, I cannot reinstall the software because I don't have the admin rights on my machine due to IT politics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I found is to directly edit the RStudio configuration files. The location of these files depends on your OS and is given in the [RStudio Help](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200532077?version=0.99.442&mode=desktop).

For my version (Version 0.99.442) and on Windows (probably on other OS'es too) you need to edit the file monitored/user-settings/user-settings. In there you can find the variable `vcsSvnExePath` (and `vcsGitExePath`), just set it to `""` to remove the reference.